# jQuery :not(:checked) not working?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<form class="pricing-downloads-right pricing-last-form" action="">
    <div class="pricing-levels-top-2">
        <input class="pricing-single-level" type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><strong>Single Level Download $49.95:</strong> Choose a single level (1 to 7) and receive access to all lessons, PDFs and review audio for that level, plus 30 days of online access ($80 value). Email us your level choice after purchase.<br>
        <input class="pricing-3-level-download" type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><strong>3 Level Download $99.95:</strong> Choose any 3 levels (1 to 7) and receive access to all lessons, PDFs and review audio for those levels, plus 60 days of online access ($190 value). Email us your level choices after purchase.<br>
        <input class="pricing-all-access-package" type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><strong>All Access Package $199.9:</strong> Receive access to all lessons, PDFs and review audio for all 7 levels, plus 90 days of online access ($300 value).<br>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-levels-2">
        <p>Which level would you like? (Click all that apply)</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
    </div>
</form>
```

and jQuery:

```
jQuery('.pricing-downloads-right input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
    if(jQuery('.pricing-levels-top-2 input.pricing-single-level:checked').length > 0){                 
          //since you don't want to target by name
          jQuery('.pricing-levels-2').show();
    }
});

jQuery('.pricing-downloads-right input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
    if(jQuery('.pricing-levels-top-2 input.pricing-single-level:not(:checked)').lenght > 0){ 
           //since you don't want to target by name
           jQuery('.pricing-levels-2').hide();
    }
});
```

So I want `.pricing-levels-2` to display when `input.pricing-single-level` is checked and to hide when it is unchecked.

Right now `.pricing-levels-2` displays when `input.pricing-single-level` is checked but it doesn't hide when unchecked.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know which value is selected from Level 1 to Level 7 when all your values for checkbox have the same value, "Bike"

Comment: Change the value of the checkbox.. Mentioned checkboxes will yield only "Bike"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you misspelled `length`:

```
if(jQuery('.pricing-levels-top-2 input.pricing-single-level:not(:checked)')
    .lenght > 0){
```

should be

```
if(jQuery('.pricing-levels-top-2 input.pricing-single-level:not(:checked)')
    .length > 0){
```

Comment: Oh, it was a grammar problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
jQuery('.pricing-downloads-right input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
    jQuery('.pricing-levels-2').toggle(jQuery('.pricing-levels-top-2 input.pricing-single-level:checked').length > 0);
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jm3sL/)

A possible better way

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $pl2 = $('.pricing-levels-2');
    var $psl = $('.pricing-levels-top-2 input.pricing-single-level');

    $('.pricing-downloads-right input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
        $pl2.toggle($psl.is(':checked')); // $ps1[0].checked
    }).change();

})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JgBDM/)